# What do those strange class names in a java heap dump mean?

Tags: java, debugging, memory-leaks, heap-memory, jmap

I'm trying to track down a memory leak in a java process, using [jmap](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html) and [jhat](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jhat.html). Every time I do this I see those weird notation for specific object types, like `[S` for string arrays and `[C` for Character arrays. I never remember what means what, and it's very hard to google this stuff.

(**EDIT**: to prove my point, it turns out that `[S` is array of short and `[C` is array of char.)

Anyone care to make a table listing all the different class names and what they mean? Or point me to such table?

Specifically I'd like to know what `[Ljava.lang.Object;` means.

Comment: Array of string should be _[Ljava/lang/String;_.

Comment: In my defense, googling led me to an article on java.sun.com which contains this line: "The String and Character array objects, [S and [C, are always going to be high on this list". Somewhat misleading.

Comment: This site also has some good information: https://communities.ca.com/web/ca-wily-global-user-community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/JNI+Signatures/contactLink

Comment: This link is broken. I hate to post links, but I'll post the updated link for the previous comment - https://communities.ca.com/docs/DOC-99575135.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You'll find the complete list documented under [Class.getName()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName()):

> If this class object represents a
>   reference type that is not an array
>   type then the binary name of the class
>   is returned, as specified by the *Java™
>   Language Specification, Second
>   Edition*.
>
> If this class object represents a
>   primitive type or void, then the name
>   returned is a `String` equal to the Java
>   language keyword corresponding to the
>   primitive type or void.
>
> If this class object represents a
>   class of arrays, then the internal
>   form of the name consists of the name
>   of the element type preceded by one or
>   more '[' characters representing the
>   depth of the array nesting. The
>   encoding of element type names is as
>   follows:
>
> ```
> Element Type        Encoding
> boolean             Z
> byte                B
> char                C
> class or interface  Lclassname;
> double              D
> float               F
> int                 I
> long                J
> short               S
> ```

Answer (score 18):

it is an array of objects as specified by [JVM Specifications](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html#14757) for internal representation of class names:

- a single [ means **an array of**
- L followed by a fully qualified class name (e.g. java/lang/Object) is the **class name** terminated by semicolon ;

so **[Ljava.lang.object;** means **Object[]**

Comment: Section 4.3.2 is probably a better reference.

Comment: that link doesn't actually describe the conventions used by Class.getName() -- in fact, the internal naming representation is quite different

Comment: furthermore the internal naming is same of Class.getName(), just replace / with .

Comment: I saw this: `org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Lj
ava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V` -- What does "IL" mean? The methods that closely match that signature are `log(Marker, String, int, String, Object[], Throwable)`, do primitives not get separated by semi-colon?

Answer (score 6):

The rules are listed in the API doc of [Class.getName()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName()).

`[Ljava.lang.Object;` would be an instance of `Object[]`. Note that multidimensional arrays
are displayed with multiple opening braces.

Answer (score -3):

Means Object[]