# How to create a Class of primitive array?

Tags: java, arrays, reflection, primitive

This question is derived from: [How to get this Method object via reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070519)

I'm trying to do the following:

```
Class c1 = Class.forName("[Ljava.lang.Integer;"); // works fine
Class c1 = Class.forName("[Lint;"); // doesn't work, since it's primitive
```

What is the workaround? `int[].class` is the only solution?

Comment: There is an other thread for this [here][1] too!

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087177/what-do-those-strange-class-names-in-a-java-heap-dump-mean

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Class c1 = Class.forName("[I");
```

See [javadoc of `Class.getName()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName%28%29) for details.

Comment: int[].class is probably better in general, but this is useful for example when using an alternative JVM language that gives access to Class but doesn't allow the PRIMITIVE[] syntax (such as e.g. Xtend)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/arrays.html) use:

```
Class intArray = Class.forName("[I");
```