# Extracting parameter types by reflection by from Constructor

Tags: java, reflection

I am trying to extract parameter types from a `java.lang.reflect.Constructor<T>` object, by using the `getParameterTypes()` method

The constructor looks like this :

```
 public SearchParameters(boolean doStaticBoosting, boolean doRewrites, boolean doCatalogsFacet, long userId,
                            Filter catalogsFilter, boolean doCatalogsFilterTypeFacet, boolean doSocialBoosting,
                            long[] categoryFilteringId)
```

Now when I invoke this method what I get the following paramter types :

[image]

As you see the last Class parameter is really messed up and defined as

> class [J

where in fact I want it to be an `long[].class`. I need to reconstruct this object later , and of course I cant do that based only on that parameter info I got.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not messed up at all. That's just the string representation of `long[].class`:

```
System.out.println(long[].class); // class [J
```

Unless you really *need* to keep the string representation somehow, you should just keep hold of the value as a `Class<?>` and all should be well.

Answer (score 2):

That is the name of the `long[]` class. Try this:

```
    long[] longs = {1L, 2L};
    System.out.println("Name is: " + longs.getClass().getName());
```

This prints:

```
Name is: [J
```

You can get the names of all the primitive array classes from the [Javadocs of Class.getName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName%28%29).

Answer (score 1):

`class [J` *is* the name of `long[].class`. Check out [`Class.getName()` JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName()).

Moreover you can create an instance of `long[].class` by using this name, see: [How to create a Class of primitive array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076690)